# SIM Card not detected after encrypting device

Tags: encryption, samsung, sim-card

I have a Samsung Galaxy Pocket Neo (Model GT-S5310B) running Android 4.1.2

The device is not rooted and the update notifier tells me I have the latest available version installed.

Today I tried encrypting the device (I did a full encryption). The encryption went smoothly and with no problems, but during boot up I noticed that the device only asked for the decryption password to continue.

My SIM card is password protected, and every time I restart or power up the device it first asks me the sim card password and THEN asks me the device password.

At first I thought that, as my device is now encrypted, the prompt for the sim card would come later. But as I logged in, I noticed the notification icon telling me that there was no sim card pluged in, and indeed, any option related to telephone would yield the same notification "Please insert a SIM card".

So I decrypted my device and thankfully,  everything is back to normal.

**My question is: Why does the device encryption make it not detect my SIM card?**

I might also add that I maintained encryption on my removable memory, it doesn't seem to affect the SIM detection, only the encryption of main memory affects the SIM card detection.

Comment: First, maybe your SIM card is old or broken.
Second, did you do the encryption phone correcly with notheng special?

Comment: *[user61456](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/61456/user61456) comments:* First, maybe your SIM card is old or broken. Second, did you do the encryption phone correcly with notheng special?

Comment: Is your phone sim-locked? Maybe additional encryption crosses some encryptions that are already there. It would be really helpful if you could introduce us to steps you made to encrypt/decrypt your device because the reason probably lies there. If after decrypting back it works all right it's definitely not SIM card itself faulty.